# Return.excess from xts gives me only 0's?

Tags: r, return, xts, zoo, zero

I have two one-column xts objects with returns and the same index and yet `Return.excess` gives me an xts output with the same index but **only 0's as values**. Why is that? Previously in my code I had no problem with `Return.excess`. And if I subtract the values by myself I definitely do not get only 0's, i.e. **the two xts-objetcs are not the same**.

My code and output as `dput`:

```
dput(test2 <- Return.excess(BAB_PF_excess_returns_adj_positive,BAB_PF_excess_returns_adj_negative))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), index = structure(c(1012435200, 1014854400, 
1017273600, 1020124800, 1022803200, 1025222400, 1028073600, 1030665600, 
1033344000, 1036022400, 1038528000, 1041206400, 1043971200, 1046390400, 
1049068800, 1051660800, 1054252800, 1056931200, 1059609600, 1062115200, 
1064880000, 1067558400, 1069977600, 1072742400, 1075420800, 1077840000, 
1080691200, 1083283200, 1085702400, 1088553600, 1091145600, 1093910400, 
1096502400, 1099008000, 1101772800, 1104364800, 1107129600, 1109548800, 
1112227200, 1114732800, 1117497600, 1120089600, 1122595200, 1125446400, 
1128038400, 1130716800, 1133308800, 1135900800, 1138665600, 1141084800, 
1143763200, 1146182400, 1149033600, 1151625600, 1154304000, 1156982400, 
1159488000, 1162252800, 1164844800, 1167350400, 1170201600, 1172620800, 
1175212800, 1177891200, 1180569600, 1183075200, 1185840000, 1188518400, 
1190937600, 1193788800, 1196380800, 1198800000, 1201737600, 1204243200, 
1206921600, 1209513600, 1212105600, 1214784000, 1217462400, 1219968000, 
1222732800, 1225411200, 1227830400, 1230595200, 1233273600, 1235692800, 
1238457600, 1241049600, 1243555200, 1246320000, 1248998400, 1251676800, 
1254268800, 1256860800, 1259539200, 1262131200, 1264723200, 1267142400, 
1269993600, 1272585600, 1275264000, 1277856000, 1280448000, 1283212800, 
1285804800, 1288310400, 1291075200, 1293667200, 1296432000, 1298851200, 
1301529600, 1304035200, 1306800000, 1309392000, 1311897600, 1314748800, 
1317340800, 1320019200, 1322611200, 1325203200, 1327968000, 1330473600, 
1333065600, 1335744000, 1338422400, 1340928000, 1343692800, 1346371200, 
1348790400, 1351641600, 1354233600, 1356652800, 1359590400, 1362009600, 
1364428800, 1367280000, 1369958400, 1372377600, 1375228800, 1377820800, 
1380499200, 1383177600, 1385683200, 1388361600, 1391126400, 1393545600, 
1396224000, 1398816000, 1401408000, 1404086400, 1406764800, 1409270400, 
1412035200, 1414713600, 1417132800, 1419897600, 1422576000, 1424995200, 
1427760000, 1430352000, 1432857600, 1435622400, 1438300800, 1440979200, 
1443571200, 1446163200, 1448841600, 1451433600, 1454025600, 1456704000, 
1459382400, 1461888000, 1464652800, 1467244800, 1469750400, 1472601600, 
1475193600, 1477872000, 1480464000, 1483056000, 1485820800, 1488240000, 
1490918400, 1493337600, 1496188800, 1498780800, 1501459200, 1504137600, 
1506643200, 1509408000, 1.512e+09, 1514505600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dim = c(192L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "portfolio.returns > portfolio.returns"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Comment: Wrapping that assignment in dput basically makes that code immediately evaporate into nothingness. I'm pretty sure that `Return.excess` must be from a package other than zoo and you have mangled the call to it anyway since you have too many parens. Close vote for not reproducible problem.

Comment: paren = parenthesis; parens = parentheses; aka "bracket" outside the USA.

Comment: So dput is meaningless here, I am rather new to coding so I dont think I know how to make a new xts with the same problem...

Comment: I'm guessing that you posted the result (a column of zeros after removing the dput and function call) rather than the input data. There's not much than can be done with that information. I've got maybe 800 packages installed and could not find any instance of a function named `Return.excess`

Comment: Its in the PerformanceAnalytics package, but I found the mistake. Its because the two return objects had the same column names... For next time, I should then rather dput the input?